# grouping in select result

Tags: oracle, select, grouping

a query delivers an Output like this

```
ID  TYPE    CN  VAL
-----------------------------
1   D   CH  A
1   K   null    null
1   K   null    null
1   K   null    null
1   D   CH  A
1   K   null    null
1   D   CH  B
1   K   null    null
2   D   CH  A
2   K   null    null
3   D   CH  C
3   K   null    null
3   K   null    null
3   K   null    null
3   K   null    null
3   K   null    null
3   K   null    null
```

i want to extend this so it Looks like

```
ID  TYPE    CN  VAL enum
-----------------------------
1   D   CH  A   1
1   K   null    null    1
1   K   null    null    1
1   K   null    null    1
1   D   CH  A   2
1   K   null    null    2
1   D   CH  B   3
1   K   null    null    3
2   D   CH  A   4
2   K   null    null    4
3   D   CH  C   5
3   K   null    null    5
3   K   null    null    5
3   K   null    null    5
3   K   null    null    5
3   K   null    null    5
3   K   null    null    5
```

how can this be done? LAG/LEAD?

Comment: think last value might work better https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions073.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to expand on my comment this should give you and idea for using last value. (not sure how you are actually ordering things so I have order by rownum which you should probably change to whatever you are ordering by)  also you may want to add some sort of case statement or decode between val and lv to make it look like your result set.  anyway mytable represents your table.

```
WITH mytable AS (SELECT   1 id,
                          'D' TYPE,
                          'CH A' CN,
                          1 val
                   FROM   DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT   1,
                          'K',
                          NULL,
                          NULL
                   FROM   DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT   1,
                          'K',
                          NULL,
                          NULL
                   FROM   DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT   1,
                          'K',
                          NULL,
                          NULL
                   FROM   DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT   1,
                          'D',
                          'CH A',
                          2
                   FROM   DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT   1,
                          'K',
                          NULL,
                          NULL
                   FROM   DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT   1,
                          'D',
                          'CH B',
                          3
                   FROM   DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT   1,
                          'K',
                          NULL,
                          NULL
                   FROM   DUAL)
SELECT   mytable.*,
         LAST_VALUE (val IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS lv
  FROM   mytable
```